# get the string after the searching for another string

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have multiple processes running as below:

```
User 18870     1  1 09:44 ?        00:03:11 java -DENV_SYSTEM_DETAILS=linux-gnu2.6.32 -DENV_PROJECT_NAME=TEST -DENV__APP_PATH=/opt/enterprise/V2.0 -DENV_DATABASE_PATH=/opt/ORACLE11G -Dswing.aatext=true -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -DsuppressSwingDropSupport=true  -Number 1234 -c 1234-SM 
User 18871     1  1 09:44 ?        00:03:11 java -DENV_SYSTEM_DETAILS=linux-gnu2.6.32 -DENV_PROJECT_NAME=TEST -DENV__APP_PATH=/opt/enterprise/V2.0 -DENV_DATABASE_PATH=/opt/ORACLE11G -Dswing.aatext=true -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -DsuppressSwingDropSupport=true  -Number 1264 -c 1264-SM 
User 18872     1  1 09:44 ?        00:03:11 java -DENV_SYSTEM_DETAILS=linux-gnu2.6.32 -DENV_PROJECT_NAME=TEST -DENV__APP_PATH=/opt/enterprise/V2.0 -DENV_DATABASE_PATH=/opt/ORACLE11G -Dswing.aatext=true -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -DsuppressSwingDropSupport=true  -Number 1634 -c 1634-SM 
User 18873     1  1 09:44 ?        00:03:11 java -DENV_SYSTEM_DETAILS=linux-gnu2.6.32 -DENV_PROJECT_NAME=TEST -DENV__APP_PATH=/opt/enterprise/V2.0 -DENV_DATABASE_PATH=/opt/ORACLE11G -Dswing.aatext=true -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -DsuppressSwingDropSupport=true  -Number 2334 -c 2334-SM
```

I would like to get output of only `-Number 1234`, the number differs from process to process. So, I need output something like below

```
-Number 1234
-Number 1264
-Number 1634
-Number 2334
```

Or with out number would be more better

```
1234
1264
1634
2334
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{print $21}'
```

Where `$21` is the position where your expected output is located having in mind that the default delimiter is a space.

```
$ echo "User 18870     1  1 09:44 ?        00:03:11 java -DENV_SYSTEM_DETAILS=linux-gnu2.6.32 -DENV_PROJECT_NAME=TEST -DENV__APP_PATH=/opt/enterprise/V2.0 -DENV_DATABASE_PATH=/opt/ORACLE11G -Dswing.aatext=true -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -DsuppressSwingDropSupport=true  -Number 1234 -c 1234-SM" | awk '{print $21}'
1234
```

Answer (score 1):

A safer and easier solution would possibly be to use the filtering capabilities provided by the tool you are using for listing processes.

That said, using `sed`, with an eye to portability and trying to minimize false positives, you can pipe your text through this:

```
sed -n -e 's/.*[[:blank:]]\{1,\}-Number[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([0123456789]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p'
```

When a line includes one or more blank characters followed by the literal `-Number` followed by one or more blank characters followed by one or more digits, the whole line is replaced with the captured sequence of digits (the part enclosed in `\(` `\)`) and the result is printed.
Note that, if the above sequence is repeated more than once in a line, only the first number is printed.

A more concise AWK alternative, assuming that `-Number` and the following sequence of digits are separated by a single space as shown in your data sample:

```
awk -v RS=' ' '/^-Number$/ { getline; print; }'
```

This treats every single-space-separated string as a record. When a record made of exactly the string `-Number` is found, the next one is read and printed.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep` or compatible:

```
ps -wwAo args= | grep -Po '^java.* -Number\s+\K\S+'
```

`-o` is a GNU `grep` extension that tells it to output the matched parts as opposed to the lines with at least one match.

`-P` is another GNU `grep` extension that tells it to use perl-compatible regexps instead of basic regular expressions.

`\K` is a perl regexp operator that resets the start of the matched portion. So the matched portion will be the sequence of one or more (`+`) non-whitespace characters (`\S`) that follows `-Number<whitespaces>`.

`ps -Ao args=` is the POSIX command to list all the argument list of all processes (concatenated with spaces). `-w` is an extension supported by a few `ps` implementation to make it *wider* (as many `ps` implementations otherwise truncate it).

Answer (score 0):

Use grep with oE

```
grep -oE "\-Number(.*?)\s-" | grep -oE [[:digit:]]+
```

-o -> to output only matching strings
-E -> Extended regex